# Spyder 4 Ipython console automatically restarts kernel after each execution

Tags: ipython, spyder

I have recently update my spyder 4 to the latest version.

I execute a code and at the end of each execution the current Ipython console where my code has just executed, automatically erase all the variable explorer and restarts the kernel.

Even when I try to stop the code at some point for debugging, it ignores me being in the debugging mode and keeps on restarting the kernel!

How can I control this behavior?

Thanks for your comments in advance

Comment: I uninstalled the anaconda and reinstall it again, it worked for me

Comment: Yeah... but should it be the only way to address the issue ? I hope not !